# i am unable to use all if statement in this program

Tags: java, variables, loops

i am unable to use if statement in whole program i.e one in public program and another in case statement  help 
and   i want the program to print either whole date if no error or just error how can i do it

```
public class date {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean yn = true;
        boolean bn = true;
        int date,
                month,
                year;

        System.out.println("Date:");
        date = kbd.nextInt();

        System.out.println("month:");
        month = kbd.nextInt();

        System.out.println("year:");
        year = kbd.nextInt();

        if (date < 0 && date > 32) {
            System.out.println("**Error** invalid day value ");
        }

        while (yn) {
            System.out.println("**error** invalid month value");
            month = kbd.nextInt();
            switch (month) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("January");
                    yn = false;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (date < 0 && date > 30) {
                        System.out.println("**Error** February has only 29 days ");
                    }
                    yn = false;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("March");
                    yn = false;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("April");
                    yn = false;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("May");
                    yn = false;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("June");
                    yn = false;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    System.out.println("July");
                    yn = false;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    System.out.println("August");
                    yn = false;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    System.out.println("September");
                    yn = false;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    System.out.println("October");
                    yn = false;
                    break;
                case 11:
                    System.out.println("November");
                    yn = false;
                    break;
                case 12:
                    System.out.println("December");
                    yn = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid month");
                    yn = true;
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me one number that is `<0` AND at the same time `>32`? Maybe you want to eliminate numbers that are `<0` OR `>32` (or maybe even <1 or >31)?

Comment: you have a semantic error as pointed by @locoyou

Comment: i used any number above 32 and below 0 it doesnt shows error

Comment: @user3443401 seriously? what is that number that above `32` and at the same time below `0`??

Comment: and one more how can i ouput program with either correct value by user or error output

Comment: 1. learn english better 2. you lack basic programming skills: that if is saying "if date is < 0 AND > 32 do something". That will never happen cuz date can't be <0 and > 32 at the same time, you agree? This is a great website but is not for total beginners...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case 2: 
         if (date <0 && date >30){
          System.out.println("**Error** February has only 29 days ");
        }
```

According to your code it should **satisfy both the conditions** (i.e) `<0 and >30` to enter the switch statement block.

so it should be the `(||)or` condition to display the statement in `case 2:`

Answer (score 1):

`&&` means logical AND. So only case expression

```
condition1 && condition2
```

could be evaluated to `true` is if both conditions would be evaluated to `true`. In other cases like if only one condition is `true` but other is `false` entire expression is evaluated to `false`.

Maybe this table will help visualize it (`T` represents true, `F` represents false)

```
 p | q | p && q
---+---+-------
 T | T |   T
 F | T |   F
 T | F |   F
 F | F |   F
```

So in case of your condition `if (data<0 && data>32)` for `data` that is `<0` like `-1` left condition `data<0` will be evaluated to `true`, but right condition will be evaluated to `false` because `-1>32` is simply not correct. So entire condition is evaluated to `false`.

What you want is logical OR operator `||` which evaluates expression to true *if at least one of its conditions is `true`*

```
 p | q | p || q
---+---+-------
 T | T |   T
 F | T |   T
 T | F |   T
 F | F |   F
```

So try maybe with `if (data<0 || data>32)`

Comment: The || truth table still says &&.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **and** operator (`&&`) to an **or** operator (`||`) in your condition. On a different note, the checks should be inclusive of 0 and 32.

```
if (date <= 0 || date >= 32){
        System.out.println("**Error** invalid day value ");
}
```

Comment: how can i input that signgle month hve 30 or 31 days